# A theorem on the order of summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could someone give (or point me to) a proof of this?

> If $\;\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty |f(i,j)| = L < \infty$
>
> and $\;\; k : N → N^2 \;\;$ is a bijection,
>
> then $\;\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty|f(k(i))| = L$.

You can assume already proved the standard inversion of limits theorem for uniform convergent sequences of functions.

Comment: Kind of immediately obvious. The partial sum sequence by definition shows absolute convergence, then every reordering of the sums converges to the same limit. $k$ is a bijection hence just a reordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that $\sum _{i=1}^{N} |f(k(i))| \leq L$ for each $n$ so $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} |f(k(i))| \leq L$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} |f(i,j)| \leq \sum _{i=1}^{\infty} |f(k(i))|$ which gives the reverse inequality. No theorem is required at all for this.